# Smallest square to wrap a cylinder

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you need to gift-wrap a cylinder (e.g., a can of tennis balls, or a large candle)
of height $h$ and radius $r$.
Here *wrap* is the natural sense of covering the surface area of the cylinder completely,
without cutting the square, creasing however needed.
What is the smallest square that suffices for a given $h$ and $r$?
For example, a rectangle of dimensions $(h+2r) \times (2 \pi r)$ suffices
for how one might wrap a can of tennis balls or a stout candle:

          
[image: Cylinder Wrapping]
   
[image: Cylinder Packaged]

In this $h=3$ and $r=1$ case, the rectangle has dimensions $5 \times 6.28$, 
and so a square of side $2 \pi$ suffices.  But is that optimal?

*Merry Christmas!*

Comment: @Alexander E.'s edit: I did mean square, for the smallest-area rectangle, can, I believe, approach the surface area of the cylinder, by using a long, thin rectangle. So I took the liberty of rolling back.

Comment: @Joseph: sorry, now I understand. I removed my edit.

Comment: @Alexandre: No problem; and sorry for misspelling your name! 

Comment: If the paper has pictures of, say, reindeer, do we need to have them come out entire on either the top or bottom or cylindrical part, or can we bend them?

Comment: @Will: That would greatly complicate the question, to require matching patterns!  Let's pursue that after solving the easier question I posed.

Comment: Joseph, good thinking. One step at a time.

Comment: How would you use an increasingly long and thin rectangle to approach the surface area of the cylinder? It seems to me that as you make the rectangle thinner and thinner, you'll have to use an growing number of switchbacks or something to cover the top and bottom, and it's not clear to me that those will be negligible in the limit.

Comment: Using square paper at a slant, I think Joseph's example can likely be wrapped with a 6 by 6 sheet, perhaps as small as 5.75. Gerhard "Ask Me About Saving Paper" Paseman, 2012.12.25

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the rules for creasing across the curved edge of the cylinder. Does the paper have to lie flat on all surfaces of the cylinder? If so, then it's not immediately clear to me that this can be accomplished with finitely many creases, even if we allow some curved creases.

Comment: @Timothy: Good question!  Perhaps it can only be accomplished, in the ideal limit, with an infinite number of creases.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Joseph can fill in this description with a picture.

In square with vertices A, B, C, and D in clockwise order, draw a line
from A to a point P on BC.  If the length of AP is longer than the
circumference R of the inscribed circle of ABP, then a cylinder with
circumference R and height which I leave you to determine can be
wrapped by ABCD.

          
[image: Gerhard's Square]

                              <sub>(Image added by J.O'Rourke)</sub>

Gerhard "Wishing You A Happy New Year" Paseman, 2012.12.25

Comment: To answer Will's earlier question, you can bend it as desired.  Alternatively, trace the pattern (say, something part of which has been provided by Joseph above) on the wrapping paper first, and then trace the square around the pattern.  You can place the reindeer parts as desired.  Gerhard "And A Merry Boxing Day" Paseman, 2012.12.25

Comment: Also, it is nice to have the circle of circumference AP also be interior to ABP, but it isn't necessary.  The circle can be broken into parts, all of which are tangent to AP, but the assembled result does not have to be inscribable in ABP.  It may be required that the circle diameter perpendicular to AP be inside ABCD, however.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Reusing Paper" Paseman, 2012.12.25

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the cylinder with a square whose diagonal has length $2(h + 2r)$: put the cylinder in the center of the square and fold the corners up to meet at the top of the cylinder. When $h/r$ is less than $\pi - 2$, this method uses less paper than the OP's method. If $h/r$ is very small (if you're wrapping a CD, for example), it uses just a little over $2/\pi$ as much paper as the OP's method.

I haven't done a comparison with Gerhard Paseman's method...

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to Vectornaut's question about wrapping with a thin rectangle.
In *[Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra](http://gfalop.org)*, 
it is argued (Theorem 15.2.1, p.236) that any polyhedron can be covered with a thin
strip with arbitrarily
small surface area beyond that of the polyhedron.
A polyhedral approximation to a cylinder then yields the claim.
This is Figure 52.2 (p.234), which gives some idea of switchback turns of the strip
used in the argument:

          
[image: turn_gadgets]

Here is a link to the original 1999 paper by Demaine, Demaine, and Mitchell,
"Folding Flat Silhouettes and Wrapping Polyhedral Packages: New Results in Computational Origami": [link](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/SoCG99/).